# General relation between closedness and convergence of convergent sequences in the set

Tags: general-topology

From what I know, closedness of a subset A of a topological space is equivalent to saying that for every A-valued convergent net the limit point belongs to A (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Topology/Nets).
But why can't we limit ourselves to sequences?
My guess is that the set of neighbourhoods of a point x belonging to the boundary of A may be uncountable and we could not construct a sequence converging to x, but would anyone be so kind to help me express it formally and, more importantly, confirm it is the right justification?
THank you for your attention and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The set of neighbourhoods of $x$ may be uncountable and yet we can still construct a sequence converging to $x$. Consider the standard $\mathbb{R}$. Then any point has uncountably many open neighbourhoods.

In fact, by considering a discrete space you can easily verify that the number of neighbourhoods can be arbitrarly large, but closures are still expressible via sequences. The number of open sets is not the point. In order to replace nets with sequences the typical setup is [the first-countability axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space). However this is not a necessary condition. For more information read about [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Some topological spaces are just too "big" in some abstract sense. Consider an ordinal $\lambda$ such that its [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality) is strictly greater than $\aleph_0$ (such ordinals exist, under ZFC it is for example the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$) and $\lambda+1=[0,\lambda]$ with the order topology. Then $\overline{[0,\lambda)}=[0,\lambda]$ because there's a net $[0,\lambda)\to [0,\lambda]$ given by $x\mapsto x$ that converges to $\lambda$. But since the cofinality is strictly greater than $\aleph_0$ than no sequence can converg to $\lambda$. We cannot reach $\lambda$ in just countably many steps, its too far away.